# Mongo marshal nested documents from struct with json annotation

Tags: mongodb, go

Following structs define the documents I want to store in a MongoDB collection (called `parents`):

```
type Parent struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Children []Child `bson:"children"`
}

type Child struct {
    Field1 string `bson:"field1"`
}
```

I get objects of following type from an external package my project depends on:

```
type LibParent struct {
 Children []*LibChild `json:"children"`
}

type LibChild struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
}
```

To insert a document in `parents` collection given an instance of `LibParent`, I can marshal the `LibParent` to json and then unmarshal it to `Parent`. Then I can use the parent instance in a call to [InsertOne](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.InsertOne).

The above example types simplify the actual types. The actual types have a ton of fields.

Is there a cleaner or more performant way to accomplish this i.e. insert a document into the `parents` collection given a `LibParent` object? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the structures are identical, you can do:

```
type LibParent struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"-" bson:"_id"`
    Children []Child `json:"children" bson:"children"`
}

type LibChild struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1" bson:"field1"`
}
```

Alternatively, if the structure fields are identical, you can:

```
var c Child
c=*(*Child)(&libChild)
```

here, `libChild` is an instance of `LibChild` with json tags, and `c` is a `Child` with bson tags. You can iterate through the children array and convert using this.

Comment: since i can't modify the library types, is your suggestion to redeclare the library types and add the bson annotation? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it appears i can convert if the types do not have nested fields. In my actual use case both parent and child have fields that are other struct types. playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/BaTlbWrHLIT